# How can I validate primitive array elements?

Tags: java, arrays, bean-validation

I just found that `@Size` also works with primitive arrays.

```
@Size(...) int[] A
```

Is there any way to validate each element in `A`?

Will following blend?

```
@Size(...) @Min(1) @Max(10) int[] A
```

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Lino I didn't try it yet. I'll update. I just want to know by the specification.

Comment: I think you have to write custom validation annotation for that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried with hibernate-validator which is the RI, I got.

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Min' validating type 'int[]'. Check configuration for 'solution.arg0'
```

`@Min` nor `@Max`, as you can see, doesn't work with primitive arrays, I think.

I still want to know if there any annotations for each element in a primitive array.